# Starting an AJP connector with "grails run-war"

Tags: tomcat, grails

How can we start an AJP connector listening on port 8009 when calling "grails run-war"?

We would like to use the embedded tomcat in production mode (with grails run-war NOT run-app), but use an AJP connector instead of the HTTP one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will completely solve your problem, but I just came across [this blog post](http://alfonsorv.com/configuring-embedded-tomcat-in-grails-development-environment/), which indicates how to create a new connector in Grails.

It lists the following to create a new AJP conenctor.

```
import grails.util.GrailsUtil
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol

eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    if (GrailsUtil.environment == 'development') {
        def ajpConnector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol")
        ajpConnector.port = 8009
        ajpConnector.protocol = "AJP/1.3"
        ajpConnector.redirectPort = 8443
        ajpConnector.enableLookups = false
        ajpConnector.setProperty("redirectPort", "8443")
        ajpConnector.setProperty("protocol", "AJP/1.3")
        ajpConnector.setProperty("enableLookups", "false")
        tomcat.service.addConnector ajpConnector
        println "Configured Tomcat ajp connector on port 8009"
    }
}
```